# Removing all text within double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on preprocessing some text in Python and would like to get rid of all text that appears in double quotes within the text. I am unsure how to do that and will appreciate your help with. A minimally reproducible example is below for your reference. Thank you in advance.

```
x='The frog said "All this needs to get removed" something'
```

So, pretty much what I want to get is `'The frog said something'` by removing the text in the double quotes from `x` above, and I am not sure how to do that. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex substitution:

```
import re

x='The frog said "All this needs to get removed" something'
res = re.sub(r'\s*"[^"]+"\s*', ' ', x)
print(res)
```

---

```
The frog said something
```

---

- `\s*` - match optional whitespace characters
- `"` - match `"` char as is
- `[^"]+` - match any character except `"` (ensured via `^` sign) one or more

Comment: This will _add_ a space if there is no `\s` surrounding the quote, but I guess that's fine.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks very much for the quick response. It will be helpful for my understanding, if you could please break down the regex within the second line of your code (just he first argument inside the re.sub function) into steps ... that way I can learn easier how to do it myself the next time around. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave, ok, see my explanations

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thank you that is helpful. One last question -- is the \s ensuring that the text within the double quotes is allowed to have leading or trailing spaces before removal?

Comment: @Dave, yes, `\s*` is optional to capture any whitespace chars, if not cutting them (whitespaces) - the surrounding multiple spaces would retain, making bigger gaps in the place of removal.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thank you, this is incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix assuming `"` are balanced in the string, i.e. are even, and double spaces are not relevant.

```
x = 'The frog said "All this needs to get removed" something'

x_new = ''.join(x.split('"')[::2]).replace('  ', ' ')
```

Eventually, these conditions can be checked with `str.count`:

```
if x.count('"') % 2 != 0:
   raise Exception('Double quotes are not balanced')

if x.count("  ") > 0:
   raise Exception('Double spaces are present')
```